# Liquibase : Load data with dates depending on today (plus one day)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, liquibase

I am using liquibase to manage my project and at launch I init my database with object as follow.

I would like to be able to init thems with dates that depends on the actual day, tomorrow at 9am for example. How to do it ?

added_entity_Booking.xml :

```
<databaseChangeLog ...>
    <changeSet id="20191214170407-1" author="jhipster">
        <createTable tableName="booking">
            <column name="id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="${autoIncrement}">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="date" type="datetime">
                <constraints nullable="true" />
            </column>
            ...
        </createTable>
        <dropDefaultValue tableName="booking" columnName="date" columnDataType="datetime"/>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet id="20191214170407-1-data" author="jhipster" context="faker">
        <loadData
                  file="config/liquibase/fake-data/booking.csv"
                  separator=";"
                  tableName="booking">
            <column name="id" type="numeric"/>
            <column name="date" type="datetime"/>
            ...
        </loadData>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

booking.csv :

```
id;date;...
1;2019-12-15T01:54:50;...
2;2019-12-14T14:55:28;...
3;2019-12-15T02:06:37;...
4;2019-12-14T15:30:05;...
```

Comment: If you would load the data with SQL inserts you could use CURRENT_DATE

Comment: Yes but the idea is to use liquibase to do it and not a lot of SQL inserts ...

Comment: This is a new feature that has been added to Liquibase in the master branch, but that has not been released yet. See https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/pull/808/files and https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2537

Answer (score 1):

According to the [liquibase docs](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/column.html) you can compute the date based on current date - with the below example for `postgresql`:

```
<column name="date" ... defaultValueComputed="now() + interval '60 days'"/>
```